# React not reloading function in JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I am using react-redux.

I have the following JSX (only relevant snippets included):

```
  getQuestionElement(question) {
     if (question) {
       return <MultiChoice questionContent={this.props.question.question} buttonClicked={this.choiceClicked} />
     }
     else {
      return (
        <div className="center-loader">
          <Preloader size='big' />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {
            this.getQuestionElement(this.props.question)
        }
      </div>
     ) 
  }
function mapStateToProps({ question }) {
  return { question };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, questionAction)(App);
```

When the action fires, and the reducer updates the question prop

`this.props.question`

I expect 
   `{this.getQuestionElement(this.props.question)}`
to be reloaded and the new question rendered.

However this is not happening. Am I not able to put a function in this way to get it live reloaded?

My MultiChoice component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
import './questions.css';

class MultiChoice extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            question: this.props.questionContent.question,
            answerArray : this.props.questionContent.answers,
            information: null
        }
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
    }
    createButtons(answerArray) {
        var buttons = answerArray.map((element) => 
            <span key={element._id} onClick={() => { this.buttonClick(element._id) }} 
            className={"span-button-wrapper-25 " +  (element.active ? "active" : "")}>
                <label>
                    <span>{element.answer}</span>
                </label>
            </span>
        );
        return buttons;
    }
    buttonClick(id) {
        var informationElement;
        this.props.buttonClicked(id);
        var buttonArray = this.state.answerArray.map((element) => {
            if (element._id === id ){
                element.active = true;
                informationElement = element.information;
                return element;
            }
            else{
                element.active = false;
                return element;
            }
        });
        this.setState({
            answerArray: buttonArray,
            information: informationElement
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="question-container">
                <div className="question-view">
                    <div className="icon-row">
                        <i className="fa fa-code" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="title-row">
                        {this.state.question}
                    </div>
                    <div className="button-row">
                        {this.createButtons(this.state.answerArray)}
                    </div>
                    <div className="information-row">
                        {ReactHtmlParser(this.state.information)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MultiChoice;
```

QuestionAction.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_QUESTION } from "./types"; 

export const fetchQuestion = (questionId, answerId) => async dispatch => {
    let question = null;
    if (questionId){
        question = await axios.get("/api/question/next?questionId=" + questionId + "&answerId=" + answerId);
    }
    else{
         question = await axios.get("/api/question/next");

    }
    console.log("question", question);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_QUESTION, payload: question  }); 
  };
```

questionReducer.js

```
import {FETCH_QUESTION } from "../actions/types";

  export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_QUESTION:
        console.log("payload", action.payload.data);
        return { question: action.payload.data, selected: false };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

index.js (Combined Reducer)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import questionReducer from './questionReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    question: questionReducer
});
```

and my entry point:
index.js

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App /> 
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

requested console.log response:

```
  render() {
    console.log("Stackoverflow:", this.props.question)
    .....
```

[image]

and after clicking the button (and the reducer updating, the console.log is updated, but the

```
            this.getQuestionElement(this.props.question)
```

does not get re-rendered

[image]

Comment: You are probably mutating the question you send in your `questionAction`, can you show your entire component ? (Or the function that dispatch the action)

Comment: I didnt realize that part was relevant, I have updated the question

Comment: Is QuestionReducer the only Reducer that you have. Please mention how have you configured your store and what you reducer input to store looks like

Comment: sure, updated. (only 1 reducer currently)

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: No errors... If I put  {this.props.question ? this.props.question.question: "none"}  to render TEXT instead of my function which renders a element, then it works and the text is updated.

Comment: Can you please add `console.log(this.props.question)` in your render function and output the log here?

Comment: Wait a minute. You set state with `question` in constructor (`MultiChoice` class). Maybe you should update this state inside `componentWillReceiveProps` or avoid its usage?

Comment: Good catch Andrew, btw the Multi Choice component should be a "dumb component" just rendering his props, you'd better handle his functionality in the parent component

Comment: sorry for my ignorance.. are you able to give an simple example of how it should be rendered? I am using a mixture of Redux store and React State, which maybe the wrong way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MultiChoice Component shouldn't store his `props` in his `state` in the constructor, you have 2 options here :

**Handle props changes in componentWillReceiveProps to update the state** :

```
class MultiChoice extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            question: this.props.questionContent.question,
            answerArray : this.props.questionContent.answers,
            information: null
        }
        this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       this.setState({ 
         question: nextProps.questionContent.question,
         answerArray : nextProps.questionContent.answers,
         information: null
       });
    }
```

We have to keep using the constructor to set an initial state as from docs :

> React doesn’t call componentWillReceiveProps() with initial props
>   during mounting.

**2nd Option : Make it as a "dumb component" by having no `state`** and only using his `props` to render something (some more deep changes in your component to do, especially to handle the "active" element, it will have to be handled by the parent component).

Comment: marking this as the answer as it solved my solution.. I scrapped using "This.state" and only use this.props and moved all logic to the parent.